# After activating htaccess in cpanel I can't log in again to my codeigniter app

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, cpanel

I'm using cpanel as online server, Initially before activating htaccess file i was able to login but after activating it I can't login again.

I don't know how to deactivate htaccess in cpanel and also i cant see httpd in cpanel. Any advice.

MY APPLICATION IS LOCATED IN SUBDOMAIN AS : example.com/project/social. where example.com is the main domain, project is a sub domain and social is a folder containing codeigniter folders.

.htaccess located in social folder also is here below

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

   RewriteBase /social/
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

 </IfModule>

 <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
 </IfModule>
```

config.php is here

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://project/social/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';
```

When i try to login via login page the following message is desplayed

```
 From project
 Hay un error en el inicio!
```

Any advice please

Comment: Well "Hay un error en el inicio!" is not something from CI by default... Did you code this error message in somewhere?

Comment: No, i didn't do that

Comment: Finding where and why that error appeared is the first step in troubleshooting your problem.

Comment: ok, but there was no any problem before activating htaccess, let me look for advice elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved, the source of problem was a single line in codeigniter in config.php file, here it is

```
$config['uri_protocol']    = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

I was able to detect the source of problem after running my application by using localhost.
Then I changed that line to

```
$config['uri_protocol']    = 'QUERY_STRING';
```

after that the problem disappeared.